# Is there a way to make NERDtree load only directories that I specify?

Tags: vim

Is there a way to make NERDtree load only directories that I specify? I don't see how to do this.

Comment: Can you give an example of the behavior you'd like to see, and an example of the behavior you're actually seeing?

Comment: When I load NERDtree I do not want it to show my home directory by default. I want it to show my project directory only. I'd like to be able to specify the directories that I want loaded.

Comment: How do you load NERDTree ? Do you have any keybindigs or do you load it directly trouch :ex mode ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea could be to use bookmarks for that purpose. For doing that, use the following sequence of commands:

- Start VIM and NERDtree inside it.
- Navigate to the directory you want to visit often, lets name that directory example `my_proj`.
- Enter the command: `Bookmark my_proj`.
- You may now open the list of Bookmarks by pressing `B`.
- Navigate to the bookmark you want to open.
- Press `RETURN` there.

The bookmark seems to be persistent, so you are now able to open a new VIM editor, and revisit the directories you have bookmarked. And you could even start the NERDtree with an additional argument, which could be a bookmark or directory (thank's [david](https://stackoverflow.com/users/344582/david) for the hint). So by entering `NERDtree my_proj`, everything is started fine.

Another idea could be to insert in your `.vimrc` file the following line:

```
:cd c:/path/To/my_proj
```

so when you start then NERDtree, your project directory should be in focus.

Comment: The NERDTree command accepts a parameter which can be a bookmark or a directory.  Map :NERDTree to something like <leader>v and you're set.  This is all in the help:  :help NERDTreeGlobalCommands